# Excel auto adding rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets

[image: 1]

The blue column in this sheet pull automatically from another sheet (Lets call it data sheet) based on certain conditions. The green columns are inputted manually. When a new row is added to the data sheet, a new row is automatically created in this sheet. My problem is that the green columns stay in the same position, and so in this example test and december which should be associated with Luka are now associated with the new data pull. Is there a way to solve this so that it creates an empty cell for the green columns?

I tried different automations but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. There is no turn-key solution to work around the issue. Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.